# how to recover my win7 on ubuntu grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

help me...
I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 above win7, unfortunately after finish installation and restart the Grub didn't appear, I look out in grub menu and win7 wasn't exist, I try to repair with win7 installation but win7 installation wasn't detect the win7,,
how to recover my win7?

Comment: Did you installed Ubuntu over the partition where Windows 7 was?

Answer (score 0):

Type the following command in terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```